# Why doesn't InstallShield Limited Edition remove AppDataFolder during uninstall?

Tags: installshield-le

I have successfully created an ISLE setup for my C# WPF app. The app needs to create XML files on the user's hard drive.

These are placed in the AppDataFolder and everything works great in my testing.

However when I test the uninstall it leaves the AppDataFolder behind.

I googled on this and there seems to be scripting capabilities in the full edition but I do not want the full edition just to have my app's AppDataFolder removed on uninstall.

I would imagine that many apps need to create and read/write to an AppDataFolder so it only stands to reason that uninstall would remove these.

I have added the folder structure that my app creates dynamically to the Install Shield, "Application Files" under the [AppDataFolder] section of the Destination Computer treeview. This shows the identical folder structure that my app creates successfully on the users hard drive.

So is it me or is it ISLE?

Thanks!!!

Comment: in my experience, if I create a new file to a folder, the folder will not be deleted during uninstallation. you can first delete the generated XML files and then unistall the program to verify this.

Comment: Full versions won't remove it either, if there is any content in the folder that was not placed there by the installer. This is common sense; if the user creates data there, the data belongs to the user. The uninstaller can't tell whether that information should be removed or not because it didn't put it there, so it leaves it. (As you should - what happens if the user places other data there (even by mistake) that is, for instance, their financial records, and your uninstall deleted it? You could be facing serious financial responsibility for damaging the user's personal data.